# Blackberry FileConnection IOException: User Key Null

Tags: java, blackberry, file-io

In my Blackberry application I am trying to write to the File System using the FileConnection class. I am able to open the file connection using:

```
(FileConnection) Connector.open(tempFile);
```

but when I call

```
tempFileConnection.create();
```

I get an IOException and the message is `User key null`.  This is only happening on the Bold 9000, on other devices it works fine.  The name of the file that I am trying to create is `file:///store/home/user/rootTest.tmp`

Does anyone know what `User Key null` actually means in this context?  Is there any reason (IT policy etc.) why I wouldn't be able to write to this directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is a mystery, not even anyone on the Blackberry developer forums can answer this one.  Chalk this up as another RIMtarded experience.